# Why is my object's value delete when I try to turn it to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The code below is returning an empty array. Why?

```
var jsonparse = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")))
console.log(jsonparse)
//it's a object which i turn to string by json.stringify
//but then i want to use it in two form one obj sec array i don't know how to turn it correctly a array
//is retuning me an empty array why? 
//expected output:-
//[{key:"value"}]
//real output
//[]
```

you can see what is in my localstorage by going to the link of an img (i have took an screen shot of my localstorage):-

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWZ9u.png

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How should we know why your array is empty? We know nothing about the return value of `JSON.parse` in your situation.

Comment: Break it down. What does `localStorage.getItem("user")` return? What does `JSON.parse(...)` return?

Comment: `Array.from` doesn’t make much sense either. It’s redundant if the JSON already represents an array and the only other type it’ll do something useful on is a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this will make the array you want:

```
var array = [];
array.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")))
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Since OP hasn't provided the relevant information, how do you know that this will return the array that they want? You seem to be guessing.

Comment: actually I'm pretty sure the problem is with Array.from. because he expects a certain value. but he get's null. the process of making array is wrong;

Comment: well @JohnColeman if it's a guess he does a right guess

Comment: I'm happy to help :) @dthedeveloper

Comment: you still have problem? @dthedeveloper

Answer (score 0):

first confirm that `localStorage.getItem("user")` is an object.
then change your statement syntax as I have written below.

```
var jsonparse =  Array.from([JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("user")))])
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("user,JSON.stringify("[{key:"value"}]") ` i have my code written like this if i do it as you say:-
`Array.from([JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("user")))]) ` 
it will return the string i send in locale storage andput it inside an array in that case i won't be able too use it